# html+php submission form fails to insert to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Its my first try to PHP and I don't have much luck.

database is created in phpmyadmin with needed tables in same order
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
5.5.49-MariaDB-1ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19 (cli)

**Content of a.html:**

```
<form method="post" action="aplicatie.php" name="ClaimForm" id="ClaimForm" autocomplete="on">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Completeaza detaliile tale:</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="numecont" accesskey="U">Numele contului</label>
        <input name="numecont" type="text" id="numecont" placeholder="ex: RSC_Alex" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="wn8overall" accesskey="U">WN8 Actual</label>
        <input name="wn8overall" type="text" id="wn8overall" placeholder="ex: 1800" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="wn8recent">WN8 Recent</label>
        <input name="wn8recent" type="text" id="wn8recent" placeholder="ex: 2700" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email" accesskey="E">Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="ex: admin@arcan.ro" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$" required />
    </div>
    <label for="tara">Tara de resedinta</label>
    <input name="tara" type="text" id="tara" placeholder="ex: Romania" required />.
    <div>
        <label for="zileonline" accesskey="X">Cate zile pe saptamana poti fi activ incepand cu ora 20:00 (GMT+2)?</label>
        <select name="zileonline" id="zileonline" required="required">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Tancuri disponibile in garaj</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="tank10" accesskey="S">Numar de tancuri de nivel 10</label>
        <select name="tank10" id="tank10" required="required">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="peste10"> >10</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="tank8" accesskey="C">Numar de tancuri de nivel 8</label>
        <select name="tank8" id="tank8" required="required">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="peste5"> >5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="careclan" accesskey="T">Pentru care din clanuri doresti sa aplici?</label>
        <select name="careclan" id="careclan" required="required">
            <option value="ARCAN">ARCAN</option>
            <option value="ARKNE">ARKNE</option>
            <option value="ARKAN">ARKAN</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Vreau sa aplic" />
```

**Content of aplicatie.php:**

```
<?php
$mysql_host     = "localhost";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "pass";
$mysql_database = "aplicatii";

$conn= new mysqli ($mysql_host,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$prepare="INSERT INTO `aplicatii1` (`wn8overall`,`wn8recent`,`email`,`zileonline`,`tara`,`tank10`,`tank8`,`careclan`,`numecont`) VALUES ($_POST['wn8overall'], $_POST['wn8recent'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['zileonline'], $_POST['tara'], $_POST['tank10'], $_POST['tank8'], $_POST['careclan'], $_POST['numecont'])";
if ($conn->query($prepare) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $prepare . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: First - learn ablout quotes, then - about prepared statements.

Comment: Put your $_POST variables inside {} so your query will become:

$prepare="INSERT INTO `aplicatii1` (`wn8overall`,`wn8recent`,`email`,`zileonline`,`tara`,`tank10`,`tank8`,`careclan`,`numecont`) VALUES ({$_POST['wn8overall']}, {$_POST['wn8recent']}, {$_POST['email']}, {$_POST['zileonline']}, {$_POST['tara']}, {$_POST['tank10']}, {$_POST['tank8']}, {$_POST['careclan']}, {$_POST['numecont']})";

also refer to http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/phpTutorial/quotes.htm

Comment: very helpful mate

Comment: @SankalpSrivastava That tutorial is atrocious compared to the [core documentation on PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). That's also 100% wrong. Do not put `$_POST` data in queries.

Comment: Hey, your `$_POST['...']` variables are not being put into quotes for the MySQL statement. Also, you should be using prepared statements like @u_mulder suggested or at least escaping your values. However, for MVP which I presume this is, your MySQL statement is missing quotes meaning your statement is being executed like so: `INSERT INTO aplicatii1 (...) VALUES (test, test, test)`   when it needs to be: `INSERT INTO aplicatii1 (...) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test')`.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I'm with @tadman on this, your code is extremely susceptible to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @nathan robb I'm not planing ro eun this over the internet. thank you...

Comment: @user3295102 is your code works ? or still not working

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $servername = "localhost";  //host name

 $username = "username"; //username

 $password = "password"; //password

 $database = "dbname"; //database name

//mysqli prepared statement 

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_select_db($conn,$database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
$Wn8overall = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['wn8overall']);
$Wn8recent = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['wn8recent']);
$Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$Zileonline = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['zileonline']);
$Tara = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['tara']);
$Tank10 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['tank10']);
$Tank8 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['tank8]);
$Careclan = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['careclan']);
$Numecont = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['numecont']);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO aplicatii1 (wn8overall,wn8recent,email,zileonline,tara,tank10,tank8,careclan,numecont)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss',$Wn8overall,$Wn8recent,$Email,$Zileonline,$Tara,$Tank10,$Tank8,$Careclan$Numecont);
            /*
                The argument may be one of four types:

                            i - integer
                            d - double
                            s - string
                            b - BLOB
                            change it by respectively
            */ 
$stmt->execute();

$row_count= $stmt->affected_rows;

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

 if($row_count>0){
    echo "New record created successfully";
 }
else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your coding standard the Error lies in the following statements that when you are submitting the variable the submit button should have a corresponding name along with the insert statement with the usage of quotes and bacticks. `You have not closed the form as per the Question you have provided`

**HTML Content:**

```
<form method="post" action="aplicatie.php" name="ClaimForm" id="ClaimForm" autocomplete="on">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Completeaza detaliile tale:</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="numecont" accesskey="U">Numele contului</label>
        <input name="numecont" type="text" id="numecont" placeholder="ex: RSC_Alex" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="wn8overall" accesskey="U">WN8 Actual</label>
        <input name="wn8overall" type="text" id="wn8overall" placeholder="ex: 1800" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="wn8recent">WN8 Recent</label>
        <input name="wn8recent" type="text" id="wn8recent" placeholder="ex: 2700" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email" accesskey="E">Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="ex: admin@arcan.ro" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$" required />
    </div>
    <label for="tara">Tara de resedinta</label>
    <input name="tara" type="text" id="tara" placeholder="ex: Romania" required />.
    <div>
        <label for="zileonline" accesskey="X">Cate zile pe saptamana poti fi activ incepand cu ora 20:00 (GMT+2)?</label>
        <select name="zileonline" id="zileonline" required="required">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Tancuri disponibile in garaj</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="tank10" accesskey="S">Numar de tancuri de nivel 10</label>
        <select name="tank10" id="tank10" required="required">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="peste10"> >10</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="tank8" accesskey="C">Numar de tancuri de nivel 8</label>
        <select name="tank8" id="tank8" required="required">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="peste5"> >5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="careclan" accesskey="T">Pentru care din clanuri doresti sa aplici?</label>
        <select name="careclan" id="careclan" required="required">
            <option value="ARCAN">ARCAN</option>
            <option value="ARKNE">ARKNE</option>
            <option value="ARKAN">ARKAN</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" name="save_form" class="submit" id="submit" value="Vreau sa aplic" />
</form>
```

**aplicatie.php**

```
<?php
$host     = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pass";
$db = "aplicatii";
$con = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$db);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
echo "Connected successfully";
if(isset($_POST['save_form']))// Here the form method will executed if it is Submitted
{
$prepare="INSERT INTO `aplicatii1` (`wn8overall`,`wn8recent`,`email`,`zileonline`,`tara`,`tank10`,`tank8`,`careclan`,`numecont`) VALUES ('".$_POST['wn8overall']."','".$_POST['wn8recent']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['zileonline']."','".$_POST['tara']."','".$_POST['tank10']."','".$_POST['tank8']."','".$_POST['careclan']."','".$_POST['numecont']."'')";
$results = $con->prepare($prepare);// Prepare the Statements Here
$results->execute();// Execute the Statement Here
$results->close();// Close the Executed Statement Here
}
?>
```

AS per the New Standard of the `mysqli.*` the use of parametrized statements is alone better and advisable. But as per your siggestion of not going to run online you can use this method and hope it will crack your error. Share thought about this code after executing it.

Comment: I still don't get anything in the table     MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0005 sec)

Comment: @user3295102. It is better to have a `Auto Increment ID` for the Table and the Table field values are too minimal. provide with the values greater the the Input that you provide in the textboxes and check. (Ex.) Provide all the table values to 100 like such and have a try. If so you face error Check upon the DB connectivity at last or else let e know if you face error again.